# Google Maps Circle Not Rendering/Showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, maps

I am using the Google Maps JS API to render a map on a site:
This map is centered on a specific point - I would like to draw a circle with this point as its center.
I have followed the example and documentation for Google Maps circles and polygons - and have no idea what I am doing wrong. It could be a stupid mistake but I am unsure. I have tried a large number of things to solve this.
In place of apiKey I have my key.

The map renders fine - it's the circle that doesn't render.

If anyone could steer me in the right direction it'd be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
    <div id="contractor__profile__map">
    </div>
    <script>
        function initContractorMap() {
            var centre = new google.maps.LatLng(57.276270031, -2.372935672);

            var mapOptions = {
                center: centre,
                zoom: 9,
                mapTypeId: 'terrain'
            };

            var newMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('contractor__profile__map'),
                mapOptions);

            var circleOptions = {
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                center: centre,
                radius: 840583700,
                map: newMap
            };

            var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
            circle.setMap(newMap);
        }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{apiKey}}s&callback=initContractorMap"></script>
```

Comment: I run your code and in my case a huge red circle around Great Britain, that reaches up to Norway, is rendered

Answer (score 0):

The problem was setting anything inside the map div to have a max-width of 100%.